# How to use golang to connect to jmx of java service and retrieve exposed MBeans

Tags: java, go, jvm, jmx, mbeans

The project needs to obtain *jvm indicators* and *Dubbo indicators* from the jmx of the service. The service implemented through java consumes more resources. It is hoped that the memory consumption can be reduced by rewriting in golang

But I don't know how to connect jmx `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port` through golang and get it from **MBean**.

I didn't find a suitable 3rd party library. Is there such a three-party library or other ways to achieve it?

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: have you tried `https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/newrelic/infra-integrations-sdk/jmx`

Comment: Recomendations are off topic is Stackoverlow. If you want to rewrite the service in Go, why do you want to connect to JMX which only is used for Java applications?

Comment: @whitespace Thank you, I checked it out, and it relies on a [third-party executable file](https://github.com/newrelic/infra-integrations-sdk#jmx-support), which is not simply written in go language. This could be a fallback to reduce resource usage

Comment: @aled Maybe I didn't express clearly, a general component implemented by go language, to connect to the JVM of the business, obtain the required MBean data and process it. This general-purpose component consumes more resources in Java, and Go has less loss

Comment: I suspect that your are out of luck because JMX seems to rely on RMI and Java object serialization. I don't think it is easy to replicate it outside Java. You would have to review JMX specifications to be sure. And as I mentioned, your question is asking for 3rd party libraries which is explicitly off-topic here.